# Preserving bundled char sequence

Tags: android

So my activity depends on a character sequence sent to it as such

```
  id = bundle.getCharSequence("id").toString();
```

This works - except every now and then if I exit the activity and return to it the data I need from

```
item  = realm.where(LogEntry.class).contains("id", id).findFirst();
```

Gets garbage collect? (not sure) - but I get a lot of errors such as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double dataObjects.LogEntry.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
```

Referring that item is now null which leads to the activity being empty.

I thought making them global would fix this, but obviously it has not. My question is - is there any way to preserve this bundled information?

Answer (score 0):

Try use breakpoints to see the content of "id" and you should try use:

> args.putString("id",stringValue); in your arg settings

and retrieve using:

> String id = args.getString("id");

Anyway, the problem seems to be LogEntry object, wich is null, the code that you provided doesn't let us know how are you creating the LogEntry object. Use the Run tab to see wich line of your code is making that exception and use breakpoints to see in what part the asignation/creation of LogEntry you are getting null.